# Entity Framework Generate Database From Model delete my data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

Is there a way to not delete the data when I do a Generate Database From Model.

The problem is when I want to add some column or a new module to an existing website, When I perform the generate database action, All my current data is lost.

I'm using Entity Framework 4

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221938/how-to-do-migration-when-generate-database-from-model-in-entity-framework-model-f